# Modification in CURL request to upload image to RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, curl, ruby-on-rails-4

I am able to upload image to RoR application(using carrierwave for image upload) through CURL request,

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-F "photo[display_photo]=@/home/Pictures/images.jpeg" \
-F "photo[name]=Flower" http://localhost:3001/photos.json
```

But i wanted to modify above command as,

```
curl -v -H "enctype: multipart/form-data" \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-type: application/json" \
-d '{"photo":{ 
 "name":"Flower", 
 "display_photo":@"/home/Pictures/images.jpeg"
}}' POST http://localhost:3001/photos.json
```

How to achieve it!!!

Comment: I guess `-F/--form <name=content>` this is what your looking for. This lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button. This causes curl to POST data using the Content-Type multipart/form-data according to RFC2388. This enables uploading of binary files etc. To force the 'content' part to be a file, prefix the file name with an @ sign.
check this SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007253/send-post-xml-file-using-curl-command-line

Answer (score 1):

The question looks incomplete. But i guess what you are trying to achieve is somthing similar to what is asked in this question:

[Curl request to upload image from local machine to ruby on rails application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401553/curl-request-to-upload-image-from-local-machine-to-ruby-on-rails-application)

- **Note:** Do remember, asking a question on **stackoverflow**, or any of its **variants**, do **keep in mind another person with the same problem faced by you**. So make questions as clear as possible, such that it helps you as well as others in the future. A few links before you frame a question:

  - [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)